# Need to better understand robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: I believe that this error form the robot_stat_publisher is because I have two different files for the model. One a urdf that for rviz and the other an sdf for gazebo. I think this is causing confusion for the publisher. I have been unsuccessful at getting a single urdf to run under both gazebo and rviz without errors.

I am publishing joint states for wheels to robot_state_publisher that does NOT translate them to tf. Rviz states that there is no transformation between map and wheel. What is robot_state_publisher doing that it thinks joint_states below are not correct?  Am I publishing the joint states incorrectly? From looking at the robot_state_publisher.cpp I can not see how it uses the joint state message. It get a tree but I have two models for the same robot. One in sdf for gazebo and one in urdf for rviz. They are loaded under different robot description params.

How can I  translate from jointStateMsg directly to TransformStamped message and bypass the robot_state_publisher?

```
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "right_wheel" from authority "/robot_state_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
```

The code:

```
void jointStateCallback1(const control_msgs::JointControllerState msg)
{
     sensor_msgs::JointState jointStateMsg;
     jointStateMsg.name.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.position.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.velocity.resize(1);
     jointStateMsg.header.frame_id = "base_link";
     jointStateMsg.header.stamp = msg.header.stamp;
     jointStateMsg.name[0] = "joint1";
     jointStateMsg.position[0] = msg.process_value;
     jointStateMsg.velocity[0] = msg.process_value_dot;
     pubJointState.publish(jointStateMsg);
}
```

From rostopic echo /joint_states

```
header: 
  seq: 1805
  stamp: 
    secs: 231
    nsecs: 908000000
  frame_id: base_link
name: ['joint1']
position: [-1.2626024562217015]
velocity: [0.015212120726772037]
effort: []
---
header: 
  seq: 1806
  stamp: 
    secs: 231
    nsecs: 908000000
  frame_id: base_link
name: ['joint2']
position: [0.632293076018593]
velocity: [0.018082079331372874]
effort: []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74500/need-to-better-understand-robot_state_publisher/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your post doesn't really contain enough information to give concrete advise.

Converting from a JointState to tf transform would basically mean to implement the robot_state_publisher yourself. You could build a custom robot-specific one, but given that you have a URDF, this shouldn't be necessary.

Basically robot_state_publisher will publish transforms for all links in your URDF, where there was joint state information received that connects those links by joints. So, if you are missing a transform, either there is no chain for that in the URDF or there is at least one joint in the URDF, where you are not publishing the specific joint state for.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0